# How to fix crash "Data <> does not represent a valid UUID" in ios 10?

Tags: ios

Our app needs to be connected to an external Bluetooth device, but I have not used a statement like [CBUUID UUIDWithData:] in my project, but I have reported error below

## 16112 NSInternalInconsistencyException

Data <02000000 192a0000 01005007 01010a50 0101> does not represent a valid UUID

CoreFoundation ___exceptionPreprocess

Comment: Try lowering the data rate. Ref: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/39094 (similar issue but no posted solution)